# JOCL Char not returning all chars

Tags: java, opencl, gpgpu, jocl

```
package parallelencode;

import org.jocl.*;
import static org.jocl.CL.*;

public class ParallelEncode {
    /**
     * The source code of the OpenCL program to execute
     */
    private static String programSource =
        "__kernel void "+
        "sampleKernel(__global const float *a,"+
        "             __global const float *b,"+
        "             __global uchar16 *c,"+
        "             __global char *d)"+
        "{"+
        "    int gid = get_global_id(0);"+
        "    c[gid] = 'q';"+
        "    "+
        "    d[gid] = 'm';"+
        "}";


    /**
     * The entry point of this sample
     * 
     * @param args Not used
     */
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        // Create input- and output data 
        int n = 17;
        float srcArrayA[] = new float[n];
        float srcArrayB[] = new float[n];
        char dstArray[] = new char[n];
        char charArray[] = new char[n];
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            srcArrayA[i] = i;
            srcArrayB[i] = i;
        }
        Pointer srcA = Pointer.to(srcArrayA);
        Pointer srcB = Pointer.to(srcArrayB); 
        Pointer dst = Pointer.to(dstArray);
        Pointer cArr = Pointer.to(charArray);

        // The platform, device type and device number
        // that will be used
        final int platformIndex = 0;
        final long deviceType = CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL;
        final int deviceIndex = 0;

        // Enable exceptions and subsequently omit error checks in this sample
        CL.setExceptionsEnabled(true);

        // Obtain the number of platforms
        int numPlatformsArray[] = new int[1];
        clGetPlatformIDs(0, null, numPlatformsArray);
        int numPlatforms = numPlatformsArray[0];

        // Obtain a platform ID
        cl_platform_id platforms[] = new cl_platform_id[numPlatforms];
        clGetPlatformIDs(platforms.length, platforms, null);
        cl_platform_id platform = platforms[platformIndex];

        // Initialize the context properties
        cl_context_properties contextProperties = new cl_context_properties();
        contextProperties.addProperty(CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, platform);

        // Obtain the number of devices for the platform
        int numDevicesArray[] = new int[1];
        clGetDeviceIDs(platform, deviceType, 0, null, numDevicesArray);
        int numDevices = numDevicesArray[0];

        // Obtain a device ID 
        cl_device_id devices[] = new cl_device_id[numDevices];
        clGetDeviceIDs(platform, deviceType, numDevices, devices, null);
        cl_device_id device = devices[deviceIndex];

        // Create a context for the selected device
        cl_context context = clCreateContext(
            contextProperties, 1, new cl_device_id[]{device}, 
            null, null, null);

        // Create a command-queue for the selected device
        cl_command_queue commandQueue = 
            clCreateCommandQueue(context, device, 0, null);

        // Allocate the memory objects for the input- and output data
        cl_mem memObjects[] = new cl_mem[4];
        memObjects[0] = clCreateBuffer(context, 
            CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
            Sizeof.cl_float * n, srcA, null);
        memObjects[1] = clCreateBuffer(context, 
            CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
            Sizeof.cl_float * n, srcB, null);
        memObjects[2] = clCreateBuffer(context, 
            CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, 
            Sizeof.cl_char * n, null, null);
        memObjects[3] = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, Sizeof.cl_char * n, null, null);

        //char *h_rp = (char*)malloc(length);
        //cl_mem d_rp = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, length, h_rp, &err);
        //err = clSetKernelArg(ckKernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &d_rp)

        // Create the program from the source code
        cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context,
            1, new String[]{ programSource }, null, null);

        // Build the program
        clBuildProgram(program, 0, null, null, null, null);

        // Create the kernel
        cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "sampleKernel", null);

        // Set the arguments for the kernel
        clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(memObjects[0]));
        clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(memObjects[1]));
        clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(memObjects[2]));
        clSetKernelArg(kernel, 3, Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(memObjects[3]));

        // Set the work-item dimensions
        long global_work_size[] = new long[]{n};
        long local_work_size[] = new long[]{1};

        // Execute the kernel
        clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue, kernel, 1, null,
            global_work_size, local_work_size, 0, null, null);

        // Read the output data
        clEnqueueReadBuffer(commandQueue, memObjects[2], CL_TRUE, 0,
            n * Sizeof.cl_char, dst, 0, null, null);

        clEnqueueReadBuffer(commandQueue, memObjects[3], CL_TRUE, 0,
                n * Sizeof.cl_char, cArr, 0, null, null);

        // Release kernel, program, and memory objects
        clReleaseMemObject(memObjects[0]);
        clReleaseMemObject(memObjects[1]);
        clReleaseMemObject(memObjects[2]);
        clReleaseMemObject(memObjects[3]);
        clReleaseKernel(kernel);
        clReleaseProgram(program);
        clReleaseCommandQueue(commandQueue);
        clReleaseContext(context);

        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(dstArray));
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(charArray));
    }
}
```

Result:

```
[?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, q,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ]
[?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, m,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ]
```

Why does it not produce a q for every one in the array, and what are the question marks? I tried changing some things, like the `int gid = get_global_id(0);` to `int gid = get_global_id(1);` and the end result was something like `[q,  ,  , ...]` and `[m,  ,  , ...]`. Can someone explain this, and how to pass multiple `char`s as input to an OpenCL kernel?

Answer (score 2):

```
 int n = 17;
```

this is okay except for buffer copies.

```
clEnqueueReadBuffer(commandQueue, memObjects[3], CL_TRUE, 0,
            n * Sizeof.cl_char, cArr, 0, null, null);
```

this reads 8 and a half `char` values or 17 bytes. A mismatch between java char (being 2 bytes) and device-side char (1 byte).

Thats why you see correct `q` at 17th  byte or 9th element.

Similar error is made with java bool arrays too.

Also uchar16 means 16 bytes.

```
    clEnqueueReadBuffer(commandQueue, memObjects[2], CL_TRUE, 0,
        n * Sizeof.cl_char, dst, 0, null, null);
```

this needs multiplication by 16 unless each element works on all 16 elements. If you have meant 17 elements each 16-bytes, then n*16 should be there and host-side(java) should give array of bytes.

Comment: So how would I input characters to the kernel?

Comment: if those are ascii chars always, you could use byte array. Otherwise, copy more bytes to/from the buffers.

Comment: So in the parameters of the kernel, I should put `__global byte *sharedByte`?

Comment: The kernel is fine and I just need to change the `char dstArray[] = new char[n];` to `byte dstArray[] = new byte[n];`?

Comment: Yes and control both sides do not go out of range.

Comment: I'm getting this error
`#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000005069db77, pid=5936, tid=0x0000000000001ed8`

Answer (score 1):

The most important point was already mentioned in [the answer by huseyin tugrul buyukisik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44723070/3182664):

A java `char` consists of **two** bytes (16 bits). In C and OpenCL, a `char` is **one** byte (8 bits).

It's not entirely clear what your program is supposed to do in the end, but as huseyin also said: I'm pretty sure that you intended to use a `char2` instead of `char16` (assuming that this will be some UTF16-related program - and otherwise, the host code would not make sense). Also, you seem to have mixed the input- and output arrays somehow.

---

## Note:

If you now change this to use `uchar2`, you may also encounter a **limitation** of OpenCL: According to the [restrictions that are mentioned on the Khronos Website](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/restrictions.html) :

> Built-in types that are less than 32-bits in size i.e. char, uchar, char2, uchar2, short, ushort, and half have the following restriction:
>
> **Writes to a pointer** (or arrays) **of type** char, uchar, char2, **uchar2**, short, ushort, and half ... **are not supported**.

---

If you describe more clearly what the program is supposed to do (and drop me a note here, as a comment), I'll try to add a small example that demonstrates how this could be approached.

Comment: Its supposed to take 4 inputs, 3 `char`s and 1 `float`. It returns the letter after based on the float number. Eg, if the input is `('a', 'm', 't', 2)`, the output would be `('c', 'o', 'v')` because 'c' is 2 after 'a', 'o' is 2 after 'm', and 'v' is 2 after 't'.

Comment: @AlexJone You could or should describe this in the question itself, by editing it. There, you also have more space than here in the comments. It's still not clear why you used a `char16`. And now, I don't know why you are passing *two* `float` arrays to the kernel when you say that you need only 1 float...